# How to push a list to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm developing a mobile application on Ionic 3.
I have a notification object on firebase database. I'm pushing data for one record like this way:

```
fireNots = firebase.database().ref('/notifications');
addNotification(notReq: INotReq){
   this.fireNots.child(notReq.RecipientUId).push({
      Title: notReq.Title,
      Body: notReq.Body
      }).then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
      })     
}
```

And this is INotReq:

```
export interface INotReq{
    RecipientUId: string,
    Title: string,
    Body: string
}
```

My data structure on Firebase:

*- notifications*
      *- Q6cQqz0OVRPCq17OWb* (RecipientUId) 
         *- LtH7QZlWVUcIpNqb-O9* 
            *- Body:"You have a notification."* 
            *- Title:"Notification Title"*

Now i need to push a list of notification (notReqs: INotReq[]). 
Should i use a for loop like this?

```
  addMultipleNotification(notificationRequestArray: INotReq[]){    
    notificationRequestArray.forEach(notificationRequest => {
      this.addNotification(notificationRequest);
    });
  }
```

Would it be a bad practice?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (at least) two other possibilities:

1. Use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) method which writes multiple values to the Database at once. See also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields).

   ```
   addMultipleNotification(notificationRequestArray: INotReq[]){
       const fireNots = firebase.database().ref('/notifications');
       var updates = {};
       notificationRequestArray.forEach(notificationRequest => {
           var newKey = fireNots.child(notificationRequest.RecipientUId).push().key;
           updates['/notifications/' + newKey] = {
               Title: notificationRequest.Title,
               Body: notificationRequest.Body
           };
       });
       return firebase.database().ref().update(updates).then(() => {...})
   }
   ```
2. Use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that will run all the asynchronous [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) operations in parallel and  "returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled":

   ```
   addMultipleNotification(notificationRequestArray: INotReq[]){
       const fireNots = firebase.database().ref('/notifications');
       var promises = [];
       notificationRequestArray.forEach(notificationRequest => {

           promises[fireNots.child(notificationRequest.RecipientUId).push({
               Title: notificationRequest.Title,
               Body: notificationRequest.Body
           })]

       });
       return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {...})
   }
   ```

---

Note that there is an important difference between the two approaches:

- By using `update()` the simultaneous updates are atomic: either all updates succeed or all updates fail.
- On the other hand, if you use `Promise.all()` some of the pushes may fail (e.g. a security rule for a specific node prevents to write) but the other ones will be successful.

---

Also, note that the advantage with these two approaches is that you know exactly **when all the writes to the database are done** and therefore you can do whatever you want in the `.then(() => {...})` method (inform the end-user, redirect to another page, etc.).